# Vector subscript out of range after push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, push

when I push_back to `vector<vector<vector<int>>> wynik` values i keep getting an error vector subscript out of range at line 1796. I used debugger to see at which line i get it and i marked it for you with <---------. I am beginner so please help me, because I dont know what is wrong. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Here is the code:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> most(vector<vector<int>> poczatek, int ilosczestawow)
{
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> wynik;
    vector<int> czas;
    for (int z = 0;z < ilosczestawow;z++)
{
    int A = dwanajmniejsze(poczatek[z])[0];
    int B = dwanajmniejsze(poczatek[z])[1];
    for(int i=1; poczatek[z].size()>3 ;i=i+4)
    { 
        int C = dwanajwieksze(poczatek[z])[1];
        int D = dwanajwieksze(poczatek[z])[0];

        if (A + C < 2 * B)
        {
            int czas1 = 2 * A + C + D;
            czas.push_back(czas1);
            int iC = znajdzindeks(poczatek[z], C);
            poczatek[z].erase(poczatek[z].begin() + iC);
            int iD = znajdzindeks(poczatek[z], D);
            poczatek[z].erase(poczatek[z].begin() + iD);
            wynik[z][i].push_back(A);
            wynik[z][i].push_back(C);
            wynik[z][i+1].push_back(A);
            wynik[z][i+2].push_back(A);
            wynik[z][i+2].push_back(D);
            wynik[z][i+3].push_back(A);

        }
        else
        {
            int czas2 = A + 2 * B + D;
            czas.push_back(czas2);
            int iC = znajdzindeks(poczatek[z], C);
            poczatek[z].erase(poczatek[z].begin() + iC);
            int iD = znajdzindeks(poczatek[z], D);
            poczatek[z].erase(poczatek[z].begin() + iD);
            wynik[z][i].push_back(A); <---------------- At this line i get an error.
            wynik[z][i].push_back(B);
            wynik[z][i + 1].push_back(A);
            wynik[z][i + 2].push_back(C);
            wynik[z][i + 2].push_back(D);
            wynik[z][i + 3].push_back(B);
        }
    }
    if (poczatek[z].size() == 3)
    {
        int C = dwanajwieksze(poczatek[z])[0];
        int czas3 = B + A + C;
        czas.push_back(czas3);
        poczatek[z].erase(poczatek[z].begin(), poczatek[z].end());
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size() + 1].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size()].push_back(B);
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size() + 1].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size() + 1].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size()].push_back(C);
    }
    if (poczatek[z].size() == 2)
    {
        int czas4 = B + A;
        czas.push_back(czas4);
        poczatek[z].erase(poczatek[z].begin(), poczatek[z].end());
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size() + 1].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][wynik[z].size()].push_back(B);
    }
    wynik[z][0].push_back(suma(czas));
}
return wynik;
```

}

Comment: You erased items from the vector over which you are currently iterating, so ilosczestawow is no longer accurate.

Comment: You need to use a debugger to view the values of your indices as well as the contents of the `vector` named `wynik`.

Comment: It looks like `wynik` always has a size of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
        wynik[z][i].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][i].push_back(C);
        wynik[z][i+1].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][i+2].push_back(A);
        wynik[z][i+2].push_back(D);
        wynik[z][i+3].push_back(A);
```

in the `if` block and the similar lines in the `else` block are a problem since they access `wynik` using indices that are not valid. You need to replace the above lines with:

```
        // Create 1D vectors
        std::vector<int> v1;
        v1.push_back(A);
        v1.push_back(C);

        std::vector<int> v2;
        v2.push_back(A);

        std::vector<int> v3;
        v3.push_back(A);
        v3.push_back(D);

        std::vector<int> v4;
        v4.push_back(A);

        // Create 2D vector by pusing 1D vectors to it.
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> v5;
        v5.push_back(v1);
        v5.push_back(v2);
        v5.push_back(v3);
        v5.push_back(v4);

        // Push the 2D vector to wynik
        wynik.push_back(v5);
```

Similar change has to be made to the `else` block.

Comment: @PawelJ, you're welcome.